# How to make nodeJS based irc client to reconnect?

Tags: node.js, irc

I'm trying to make an nodejs based IRC web client (using https://github.com/martynsmith/node-irc and socket.io), and I have some problems.

When i start the server, and connect to it the first time, everything works ok, the client gets the "registered" event and everything works after that.

If i refresh the page, the server still gets the init event (with the server and nickname), but the IRC client doesn't connect (tries to reconnect after 4000ms but everytime it gets a "Connection got 'close' event" message).

Code:

Client-side:

```
var socket;
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
...
socket.emit('init', { nick: $(".popup #nume").val(), channels: channels });
```

Server-side:

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);

irc = require('irc');

console.log("Started server..");

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('init', function(data) {
                console.log('io connection with id ' + socket.id);
                console.log('socket length: ' + sockets.length);

                var first, i, good, new_message;

                sockets.push(socket);

                socket.nickname = data.nick;
                socket.channels = data.channels;
                first = 0;

                console.log('Init from : ' + socket.nickname + ' ' + socket.channels);

                socket.client = new irc.Client('localhost', socket.nickname, {
                        port: 6667,
                        debug: true,
                        showErrors: true,
                        autoRejoin: true,
                        autoConnect: false,
                        channels: socket.channels,
                        secure: false,
                        retryDelay: 4000,
                        retryCount: 1000
                });

                socket.client.connect();

                socket.client.addListener('registered', function(message) {
                        socket.client.list();

                        console.log('Registered to irc');
                });
```

Logs:

```
io connection with id oFrdaN8WhQAE4mEh62uI
socket length: 1
Init from : test 
8 Jun 04:33:50 - SEND: nickserv :ghost test
8 Jun 04:33:50 - SEND: NICK test
8 Jun 04:33:50 - SEND: USER nodebot 8 * :nodeJS IRC client
Netrror: Error: write EPIPE
8 Jun 04:33:50 - Connection got "close" event
8 Jun 04:33:50 - Disconnected: reconnecting
8 Jun 04:33:50 - Waiting 4000ms before retrying
```

So, the problem is that even if it connects to the server, it is unable to connect to the IRC server (everytime it gets a "Connection got 'close' event" message).

Comment: `irc` is client library for IRC for node.js. How are you starting the IRC server ?

Comment: I'm starting the IRC server from the command line:

node server.js